# How to call AWS Lambda concurrently without having thousand of connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, concurrency, aws-lambda

I am trying to call AWS Lambda concurrently to **scrape** some urls. When doing so I use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to invoke the lambda. I split the urls into batches of size of 50 to limit the number of concurrently running lambdas. I then wait for them to end, and expect the number of connections to be limited by 50. But, instead I see boto3 creating > 1000 connections.

Here is the code:

```
def scrape(data):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        result = []
        for source_url, info in data.items():
            urls = info['urls']
            source = info['source']
            for batch in batches(urls, 50):
                futures = []
                for url in batch:
                    payload = {
                        'url': url,
                        'country': source['country'],
                        'language': source['language'],
                        'topic': source['topic']
                    }

                    futures.append(
                        executor.submit(client.invoke,
                                        FunctionName='scrape_page',
                                        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                                        Payload=bytes(json.dumps(payload), 'utf-8')))

                result.extend([future.result() for future in futures])

    return [json.loads(r['Payload'].read().decode('utf-8')) for r in result]
```

**Is this a correct approach to call AWS Lambda concurrently, or there is a better way?**

Comment: "Connections" to what?

Comment: Please tell us EXACTLY where & how you measured the number of connections & which connections are you referring to? The Lambda function's connection to the URL?

Comment: I run the script given above, as I understand the boto3 client creates new connection to lambda each time it is being called. I try to limit total number of connections to 50 total, but when running `netstat | grep ec2` I see that the number of connections grows to hundreds, instead of being ~50.

Comment: I haven't tried this, so not an answer. It looks like the default number of pooled connections is 10, which I think means that Boto will create 40 new one-time-use connections for each batch of 50 requests that you make. You can change this, by [passing a config object](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html) when creating the client.

Comment: That said, your architecture doesn't really leverage Lambda. Rather than invoke Lambdas from your client program, I would instead write the URLs to an SQS queue and let Lambda handle the invocations itself. The resutls can either be written to a different SQS queue and read by your application, or better, to a DynamoDB database or S3 bucket, where they can be read multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs to provide more details like others mentioned,however would like to point out few things.

- Instead of using threads inside the lambda you can make your task
  idempotent and distribute them to multiple lambda.
- Number of cores(1 core=2 threads) available to a lambda is
  proportional to Function memory and only when you choose memory size
  more than 1.8G you will get more than 1 core.And afaik you will not
  get more than 2 cores with max memory setting.
- You can cap the concurrent execution by configuring the Reserved
  Concurrency ,which will guarantee that at any point the number of concurrent
  lambda will not exceed the configured number.